# How to fix circular dependency with GraphQL Relay connections

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

I have separated out my connection to its own file and can use it in my root query (it worked fine when the connection was defined in the type), but when trying to use it by importing it to the type the connection is for I just get back:

> Error: PageEdge.node field type must be Output Type but got: undefined

I can get the connections working in my QueryType, but not PageType. My schema is roughly like this.

```
QueryType {
  pages: [PageType]
}

PageType {
  _id: string
  pages: [PageType]
}
```

Here is a link to the project repo where the graphql stuff is (I just pushed a commit with it erroring to see all the code):
https://github.com/DaveyEdwards/myiworlds/tree/master/src/data

I have made QueryType and PageType fields thunks (the solution that seems to fix most peoples problems) and also tried making a thunk out of interfaces:

```
interfaces: () => [nodeInterface]
```

I would think this is a very common problem for anyone building an app with users and friends.

```
UserType: {
  friends: [UserType]
}
```

**My PageType:**

```
import { nodeInterface } from '../nodeInterface';
import PageConnection from './connections/PageConnection';

const PageType = new ObjectType({
  name: 'Page',
  description: 'Everything you see can be placed inside a page.',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('Page', page => page._id),
    _id: {
      type: new NonNull(ID),
      description: 'A unique id used to instantly locate this page inside the database',
    },
    pageEdge: {
      type: PageConnection,
      args: connectionArgs,
      resolve: async (page, { args }, { loaders }) => {
        if (page.pageEdge) {
          const pageEdge = await loaders.pageLoader.loadMany(page.pageEdge);
          const connection = connectionFromArray(pageEdge, args);
          return connection;
        }
      },
    },
  }),
  interfaces: () => [nodeInterface],
});

export default PageType;
```

**My PageConnection:**

```
import { connectionDefinitions } from 'graphql-relay';

import PageType from '../PageType';

const { connectionType: PageConnection } = connectionDefinitions({
  name: 'Page',
  nodeType: PageType,
});

export default PageConnection;
```

**My nodeInterface:**

```
import { nodeDefinitions } from 'graphql-relay';
import { getNode, getNodeType } from './type-registry';

export const { nodeInterface, nodeField } = nodeDefinitions(getNode, getNodeType);
```

**My type-registry:**

```
import { fromGlobalId } from 'graphql-relay';
require('babel-polyfill');

const types = {};

export const registerType = (model, type, lookupFn) => {
  types[type.name] = { model, type, lookupFn };
};

export const getNode = async (globalId) => {
  const { type: typeName, id } = fromGlobalId(globalId);
  console.log('getNode', globalId, typeName, id);

  if (types[typeName]) {
    const object1 = await types[typeName].lookupFn(id);
    const Class = types[typeName].model;
    // let result  = Object.create(types[typeName].model, object1);
    const result = new Class(object1);
    console.log('getNode result', result);
    return result;
  }
  return null;
};

export const getNodeType = (obj) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(types);
  let ret = null;
  keys.map((typeName) => {
    if (obj instanceof types[typeName].model) {
      ret = types[typeName].type;
    }
    return true;
  });
  return ret;
};
```

**My QueryType where the imported connection works**

```
import {
  GraphQLObjectType as ObjectType,
  GraphQLList as List,
  GraphQLString as StringType,
} from 'graphql';
import { connectionArgs, connectionFromArray, connectionDefinitions } from 'graphql-relay';
import { nodeField } from '../nodeInterface';
import PageType from './PageType';
import { getPageList } from '../queries/googleDatastore/pageQueries';
import PageConnection from './connections/PageConnection';

const QueryType = new ObjectType({
  name: 'QueryType',
  fields: () => ({
    pages: {
      type: PageConnection,
      args: connectionArgs,
      resolve: async (obj, args) => {
        const response = [];
        try {
          const pageEdge = await getPageList();
          const connection = connectionFromArray(pageEdge, args);
          return connection;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('pages err', err);
        }
        return response;
      },
    },
    node: nodeField,
  }),
});

export default QueryType;
```

**Resources for this issue I have been trying to get working:**

Parts of this repo is what I was implementing to get connections working in the first place
https://github.com/bondz/learn-graphql-relay/blob/47211fdec44ce4bb10f487bddfc7411e5690b894/src/types/projectConnection.js

[Edge.node field type must be Output Type but got: undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993661/edge-node-field-type-must-be-output-type-but-got-undefined)

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/612

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/373

https://gist.github.com/fbaiodias/77406c29ddf37fe46c3c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the `import PageConnection` at the top of `PageType.js` and use a runtime require:

```
...
pageEdge: {
  type: require('./connections/PageConnection'),
  args: connectionArgs,
...
```

Comment: This returned Error: Page.pageEdge field type must be Output Type but got: [object Object].

Comment: Also tried putting the require inside a function and calling 
type: pages() and pages()[0/1] with still nothing

Comment: Try `require('./connections/PageConnection').default`

Comment: OMG thank you both SO much!!!! Spent over 3 days working on this and was about to put the connection back in the type.  I also had to add one more thing because it was giving me "Cannot read property 'after' of undefined".  I replaced {args} with {...args} in the resolve method and it fixed it

Comment: I was about to go crazy before I saw this solution. Saved my day, thank you.